# What does "storage" mean in relation to Mini Panels?

Tags: panels, features

I am working on a site that uses Mini Panels.  In the Mini Panels List I see a column called "STORAGE".  The column contains the values, overridden, default, and normal (which is the storage for a Mini Panel I just created).

What does "storage" mean in relation to Mini Panels and what do each of the storage values (overridden,  default, and normal) mean?

One of the reasons I am asking this is because I have a Feature that is stuck in the Overridden state and the default and overriden diff shows:

```
DEFAULT                                     OVERRIDES
PANELS_MINI
Line 335                                    Line 335
  'renderer' => 'standard',                 'renderer' => 'standard',
- 'storage_id' => 'article_header',
- 'storage_type' => 'panels_mini',
```

So, my next question is: What is a storage type of "panels_mini" and how is it related to the three other types of storage mentioned above?

Thanks

Comment: Normal should be what you created. Overridden should be anything from a module or features that has been changed. And default when they're not changed. I'm not adding this as an answer because I'm not 100% on it.

Comment: Niall, Thanks.  I am really trying to find out what the concept of storage means in this context.  What exactly are we storing?  Or perhaps the word, "storage," is a misnomer that meant something at one time?  And, why is this piece of metadata so important that it has its own column in the Mini Panels List?

Comment: Well a default or a feature would be actual code in a php file whereas normal would be code stored in the database. That's my guess about what storage means.